# removing block quote from Wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code which puts the content of a Wordpress post onto the page (the images were removed)

```
<?php
  $content = preg_replace('/<blockquote>(.*?)<\/blockquote>/', '', get_the_content());
  $content = preg_replace('/(<img [^>]*>)/', '', get_the_content());
  $content = wpautop($content); // Add paragraph-tags
  $content = str_replace('<p></p>', '', $content); // remove empty paragraphs
    echo $content;
?>
```

I want to remove the blockquote as well, which it does, HOWEVER placed where it currently is it does not remove the blockquote.

Placed after the 'img' line it DOES remove the block quote but the images are put back in

Comment: try this : `$pattern = '/<blockquote>(.*?)<\/blockquote>/,/(<img [^>]*>)/';`
`$content = preg_replace($pattern, '', get_the_content());`

Comment: where do I put that in my code? just replace the blockquote line?

Comment: yes instead of blockquote and img..

Comment: throws an error. Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier ','

Comment: sorry also `$replacement = ',';` and `$content=preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, get_the_content());`

Comment: do I add those two or replace what I have with them? Tried a few different ways still throwing same error

Answer (score 0):

You should use

[strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) — Strip HTML and PHP tags from a string

```
$string = get_the_content();

// remove all html tags
echo strip_tags($string); 

// Allow specific tags such as <p> and <a>
echo strip_tags($string, '<p><a>');
```

Comment: @user3550879: You just need to write all desired tags in second argument of strip_tags. other all tags will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the styled quotation mark in the blockquote element, you'll need to modify the ::before pseudo-element, which contains: `content: "`

CSS to add:

```
blockquote::before {
    content:none;
}
```